# uBlock Origin blocks all connection of UnGoogled-Cromium Web-Browser

Tags: networking, browser, extension

After updating **UnGoogled-Chromium Web-Browser** to the latest version:

```
Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build, ungoogled-chromium) Ubuntu (64-bit)
```

The browser extension **uBlock Origin** blocks any connection of the UnGoogled-Chromium Web-Browser.
As soon as I disable **uBlock Origin**, the browser works.
I then uninstalled **uBlock Origin 1.33.2** and installed the latest version **1.40.8**, no change, the extension blocks all connections of the web browser.
What can I do?
I need this script and add blocker, is the best one.

Comment: Weird, I'm using the same version of uBlock but cannot reproduce this. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Report this issue to [ublock maintainer](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uBlock-issues/issues), possibly to [ungoogled maintainer](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium/issues) too. This isn't about Ubuntu.

Comment: Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04, 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5, 
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0, 
Qt Version: 5.12.8, 
Kernel Version: 5.11.5-custom, 
OS Type: 64-bit, 
Processors: 8 × AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, 
Memory: 13.7 GiB of RAM